# which find -exec convert command to use in order to concatenate n pdf files into one?9sa

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, find

I have in my linux:

`1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf 4.pdf ... n.pdf`

Which find -exec (with convert command) to use in order to connect all pdf into a single one?

`output.pdf`

so far i used

`convert 1.pdf 2.pdf output.pdf`

but i'm trying to have it working for n pdf files.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pdftk`:

```
pdftk `find . -name "*.pdf"` cat output output.pdf
```

Comment: thanks. it did the job well.  and also i found that pdftk generated better looking pdf did not loose quality. however i really thought i could use find command without `` tags i thought find exec support out of the box runing a command on the list of its file results and then i can add more commands to it (the aggregation into a single find) I always feel like i'm doing something wrong not nice and clean i'm trying to use the commands as is and not append to them `` :) maybe just my feeling...

Answer (score 1):

How many PDF files are you looking at?

Can you just do something like this:

```
convert *.pdf output.pdf
```

Granted, it's not as cool or scalable as using `find`, but it may be a quick and easy way to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try something like

for i in {1..n}; do convert output.pdf ${i}.pdf output.pdf; done